# Some ideas on how to block a wheel on a metallic rod?

Tags: repair, metal

I manage somehow to put some old inline roller wheel to some old trolleys I use in my house for shopping (and trekking). The average weight is about 20-30 kg. I am looking for a way to fix those wheels knowing that, I only have some basic tools (no electric ones). I'm looking for a cheap solution, I dont want to invest more than a couple of dollars to fix those wheels.

I'm looking for a simple and smart idea to prevent the wheel from getting out of the rod

the big trolley rod is quite long, I might cut it. the small trolley rod is more tricky.

The best way would be to thread the rod, but it would only work for the big trolley since the short trolleys's rod is not long enough (only 3 mm are cylindrical, the remaining part, 7 mm, has been too much filed to put the wheel on it, and it has a kind of conic shape). But anyway I don't have the thread tool so it's out of question. Drilling the rod to fit a pin would be great but, once again, no drilling machine.

I thought about using hose clamp, but I'm afraid the wheel will make it turn with it, and damaging the hose clamps. I also though about using some sort of "weld epoxy", (I would just file the resin to change the wheel when needed) but I'm not sure it will be strong enough.

Any creative idea and advice would be very appreciated.

This is the big trolley:

[image]

This is the small (foldable) trolley:
[image]

Comment: What originally held the wheels on? Was there some kind of a cap/nut/spacer?

Comment: The small the bar had a mushroom shape (it had been smashed with a lot of pressure) that's why I had to file it and ended up with the conic shape. For the big one, the wheel were bigger and hold by a cap but that won't work for the small inline skate wheel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a hacksaw (or just a hacksaw blade if you don't own a hacksaw) to make a groove all around the rod. If you had a small electric grinder (Dremel or similar) that would also be an option, but the hacksaw will work and is a hand tool.

Use an "E-clip" in the groove (perhaps with a washer towards the wheel, first.)

[image]

Comment: What a great idea! Thanks so much! I wonder which e-clip to buy. My rods' diameters are 8mm and 10mm : ● should I buy e-clips of diameter 8 and 10mm or ● should I buy e-clips with a diameter of 2 millimeter below to compensate the loss due to the groove. For instance using for the rod of 8mm an e-clip with a diameter of 6mm.

Comment: Depends on where the nominal size is measured from. Looking at McMaster, they list a range of shaft sizes, and the size of the inside of the groove, which does suggest slightly smaller than the shaft as the probable "size" - they just don't list that as a "size" in and of itself. 6-8mm shaft; 5mm groove. 7-9; 6 - 8-11; 7 - 9-12; 8 - 10-14; 9

Answer (score 4):

Axle cap nuts (or axle hat nuts) are designed for this use.  You just press them onto the smooth axle. The trick may be finding just the right size.

[image: Axle Cap Nuts]

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot find the e-clips (as presented in @Ecnerwal answer), use some bailing wire (or some type of form-able, solid wire which can be wrapped around the axle at the groove. I know this wouldn't be as pretty as an e-clip, but you might not be able to readily find e-clips of the size you'd need to make this happen.

Something else you could try as well is to cut the ends of the bar down so you have a short length of rod sticking out, place the flat washer next to the wheel, then mushroom the ends of the rod to keep the washer in place.

Comment: That very good to know your those two tricks. Since I travel a lot and developing countries, I am always looking for those handy solution! I wonder what is the best way to tie the bailing wire. If you have a picture I would be happy to see how you do it!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to [tin solder](https://youtu.be/iQuz1lmysYQ?t=363) the bearing on the rod:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: While this may work, it is, effectively a link-only answer. As soon as that YT video is taken down, this becomes useless. Please include some description from the video itself, or this answer will likely be deleted.

Comment: @FreeMan, I understand your point but it wasn't a link-only answer as the picture was a printscreen (not an embed of the link) and thus would have remained in the answer even if the YT video were taken down.  But for the sake of clarity, I have added 2 more printscreens.